# Are there any downsides to not broadcasting a router's SSID?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, privacy

Besides the obvious (not being able to use a standard UI to detect and connect to an available network), are there any downsides to **not** broadcasting a router's SSID?

I had read that it causes all devices (that are configured to connect to that *semi-hidden* network) to constantly broadcast the SSID of the *semi-hidden* network.  That would be a downside, if true.

(I use the term *semi-hidden* because although the SSID is not broadcast by the router, it can still be determined using specialized tools.)

Comment: This answer from [information security](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74658/security-risks-of-disabling-ssid-broadcast) should be able to answer your question.

Comment: @DrZoo Thank you.  I will read it now.  Much appreciated.